# Bounced Sessions vs 1 Pageview Sessions

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

From my understanding, a bounced session is a session with one page view only. However, today on Google Analytics I chose the following two segments:

- Bounced Sessions
- Custom Segment; Filter used Pageviews = 1

The number of sessions for the custom segment was nearly 20% higher than the number of sessions for the Bounced Sessions segment.

I'm confused as to why both segments didn't give me the same number of sessions. Do I have the concept of bounce rate messed up? If so could you help me understand better what Google Analytics counts as a bounce?

Comment: Bounces are sessions with only one user interaction (not just pageviews, but also events, user timings etc.), so check first if there is e.g. event tracking without a non-interaction flag. Also pre-calculated reports and ad-hoc reports do not always match because they might use different sample sizes (on large sites at least). Not sure this is actually on-topic for SO (as no code is involved).

Answer (score 0):

Bounce session - is session with only one GET query to the one to one pixel file on google-analytics.com. Сonsequences are follows.